# Issue with TSQL Query only returns months that have values and not 0 as needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following TSQL returns last 6 month count of data, but if a month does not have records it does not just return 0 as I need it to do, how can I make it do so?

```
declare @thismonth as Date = DateAdd(d, 1 - DatePart(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
declare @firstmonth as Date = DateAdd(m, -6, @thismonth);

SELECT YEAR(StartDate) year,
       MONTH(StartDate) month,
       COUNT(StartDate) EmployeeStartet
FROM
    EFP_EmploymentUser
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN @firstmonth AND @thismonth
GROUP BY YEAR(StartDate), MONTH(StartDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(StartDate) DESC, MONTH(StartDate) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
declare @lastMonth as Date = DateAdd(d, 1 - DatePart(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
declare @firstMonth as Date = DateAdd(m, -6, @lastMonth);

WITH months AS (
SELECT @firstMonth AS thisMonth
UNION ALL
SELECT DateAdd(m, 1, thisMonth) AS thisMonth
FROM months
WHERE thisMonth < @lastMonth
),
data AS (
-- your sql here
SELECT YEAR(StartDate) year,
       MONTH(StartDate) month,
       COUNT(StartDate) EmployeeStartet
FROM
    EFP_EmploymentUser
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN @firstmonth AND @thismonth
GROUP BY YEAR(StartDate), MONTH(StartDate)
)
SELECT 
  YEAR(m.thisMonth) AS year,
  MONTH(m.thisMonth) AS month,
  ISNULL(d.EmployeeStartet, 0) AS EmployeeStartet
FROM months m
LEFT OUTER JOIN data d
ON 
      d.year = YEAR(m.thisMonth)
  AND d.month = MONTH(m.thisMonth)
ORDER BY m.thisMonth DESC
```

Comment: Hello Bastian .. I am not sure what SQL you want med to place after "data AS" since I have only one column containing dates, and from that I need to find month, year and count of dates in that month .. I do not have a column for each of Year, Month and Data.

Comment: Ahhh, Okay that makes sense to me no .. Brilliant Bastian, the result is perfect now, Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Left join your data to a tally

```
declare @thismonth as Date = DateAdd(d, 1 - DatePart(d, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
declare @firstmonth as Date = DateAdd(m, -6, @thismonth);

with m as (
  select  @firstMonth md union
  select  DateAdd(m, 1, @firstMonth) union
  select  DateAdd(m, 2, @firstMonth) union
  select  DateAdd(m, 3, @firstMonth) union
  select  DateAdd(m, 4, @firstMonth) union
  select  DateAdd(m, 5, @firstMonth)
),
ym as (
   select YEAR(md) y, MONTH(md) m
   from m
)
select ym.y, ym.m, COUNT(e.StartDate) EmployeeStartet
from ym
left join EFP_EmploymentUser e
   ON  (e.StartDate BETWEEN @firstmonth AND @thismonth) 
   AND ym.y = YEAR(e.StartDate) AND ym.m = MONTH(e.StartDate)  
GROUP BY ym.y, ym.m
ORDER BY ym.y DESC, ym.m DESC;
```